# Eclipse: Chain many 'Run as Java Application' one after another

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, microservices

I have built a microservices architecture around many spring boot applications. I have 5+ applications. And I have to individually go to each application in eclipse and start them one after another in a specific order.

[image: eclipse running a java application]

Is there any way in which I can do this all at once in eclipse? . One click and many java applications run post the successful startup of the previous in a desired order.

Comment: make a bash/shell script? Any reason you run it directly from Eclipse?

Comment: Parallel running, on different ports? Or one after the other, ending with the start of the next?

Comment: I use eclipse to manage multiple applications more for ease of access. All of them are running on different ports. Not ending with the start of the next

Comment: Consider using Docker and docker-compose. It helped me to launch a bunch of microservices fairly easily, ready for the delivery and also easy to develop in localhost with no dependency on an IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a 'Launch group' under 'Run configurations' where you can concatenate them

[image]

Comment: This answers the question. However is there any way I can make the next application in the queue wait until the first one starts up. In my case a spring boot app

Comment: Yes, shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0-cO9wZj6w&t=20s

Comment: Eclipse always surprises me :)
Thanks for the answer.